# possible to get same keys' values from a list in django?

Tags: python, arrays, django, list

is there a possible way without looping to get all the same key's value from a list?

For example.  I made this query

`users = User.objects.filter().values('id', 'email', 'something_else')`

`users` would then look like

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'email': 'email@email', 'something_else': 'something?'},
    {'id': 2, 'email': 'email2@email', 'something_else': 'something?'},
    {'id': 3, 'email': 'email3@email', 'something_else': 'something?'}
]
```

but then from `users` is it possible to then return all the `id` only? e.g. [1,2,3]

I know we can do a loop then `extend` it to a list but possible to do without looping or faster way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: **is it possible to then get all the id only? e.g. [1,2,3]** `users = User.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)`

Comment: When you say **all the same key's value from a list**, same as what? do you want to group records that have same values for a specific fields?

Comment: @Lemayzeur but because all other values will be used for other purpose first, then need just the ids after

Comment: can you update your question to show what the result expected from your given sample? it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
list(map(lambda x: x['id'], users))
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Alternatively, using `operator.itemgetter` which typically runs a bit quicker:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter('id'), users))
```